# How should i traverse inside two dimensional array list using for each loop

Tags: java, arraylist, traversal

```
public List<String> findItinerary(List<List<String>> tickets) {
    // creating adjencency list
    
    for(String[] ticket : tickets)
    {
        map.putIfAbsent( ticket[0] ,new PriorityQueue<String>());
        map.get(ticket[0]).add(ticket[1]);
    } 
    dfs("JKF");
    return path;
}
```

I m trying to create the adjacency list here, but having problem to iterate through list inside the tickets. I was using for each loop , and coming across this error **"List cannot be converted to String[]
for(String[] ticket : tickets)"**

Comment: The members of `tickets` are `List<String>`, not `String[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `String[]` where you should be using `List<String>`. Change your code to this:

```java
for(List<String> ticket : tickets)
{
    map.putIfAbsent(ticket.get(0), new PriorityQueue<String>());
    map.get(ticket.get(0)).add(ticket.get(1));
}
```

**Update**

If you want to convert the `List<String>` in an array use this snippet:

```java
String[] array = new String[ticket.size()];
ticket.toArray(array); // fill the array
```

Comment: But, lets consider the case if i want to Convert inside for each loop List<String> tickets to  String[] , how should i do it ?

Comment: A better question would be why? How is that profitable in any way?

Comment: @user16824117 check the update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way.

- use  [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) which puts the value in for the key.
- then  it returns either the existing value or the one just entered.
- then there is no need to lookup the key for insertion

```
public List<String> findItinerary(List<List<String>> tickets) {
    // creating adjencency list
    
    for(List<String> ticket : tickets)  {
        map.computeIfAbsent( ticket.get(0), v->new PriorityQueue<String>())
                                  .add(ticket.get(1));
    } 
    dfs("JKF");
    return path;
}
```

As far as returning `path` I don't see it defined anywhere.